# How can I average N images without keeping all images in memory, using OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, average

I've created a class that attempts to create an average image from any number of images (passed one by one).

This process will run in it's own thread, while other threads read in images, do processing, and pass the output to this average object.

Unfortunately, the averaged image gets brighter, and brighter, with each additional image. 
I suspect that there is an error in my averaging function, but I have been unable to find it.

Edit: I was missing the "curImg/curCount" part of the equation. With this correction, the images now get dark. I am not left with a good average.

Edit 2: I see that I was down voted. Is there something I could do to improve this question?

```
class AverageImage {
    private Vector<Mat> average = new Vector<>();
    private int count = 0;

    public void add(Mat img) {
        count++;
        Vector<Mat> splitImg = new Vector<>();
        Mat convertedImg = img.clone();
        convertedImg.convertTo(convertedImg, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Core.split(img.clone(), splitImg);

        if (average.isEmpty()) {
            average = splitImg;
        } else {
            // prevAverage * (prevCount/curCount) + curImg/curCount
            for (int i = 0; i < average.size(); i++) {
                Core.multiply(average.get(i), new Scalar((count - 1) / ((double) count)), average.get(i));
                Mat temp = new Mat();
                Core.divide(count, splitImg.get(i), temp);
                Core.add(average.get(i), temp, average.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public Mat getAverage() {
        Mat convertedAverage = new Mat();
        Core.merge(average, convertedAverage);
        convertedAverage.convertTo(convertedAverage.clone(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        return convertedAverage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor comment: `convertedImg` is not being used at all in your code.  You can remove it.

---

Your determination of what is known as the [cumulative mean](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/cumumean.htm) is correct.  However, the part that is really messing with you is the `divide` statement:

```
Core.divide(count, splitImg.get(i), temp);
```

[By consulting the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#divide), when you call the variant which the first element is a scalar, the operation that is being done is:

```
dst(I) = saturate(scale / src(I))
```

`scale` is used to divide into the output.  Therefore, what you are doing is `count / splitImg.get(i)` when you should actually be doing `splitImg.get(i) / count`.  With this in mind, `divide` does not support taking an image and dividing by a coefficient.  However, a workaround is to use `Core.multiply` with the inverse of `count`:

```
Core.multiply(splitImg.get(i), new Scalar(1.0 / count), temp);
```

All you need to do is change the `Core.divide` statement to the one above and it should work out.

```
        // prevAverage * (prevCount/curCount) + curImg/curCount
        for (int i = 0; i < average.size(); i++) {
            Core.multiply(average.get(i), new Scalar((count - 1) / ((double) count)), average.get(i));
            Mat temp = new Mat();
            // Core.divide(count, splitImg.get(i), temp);
            Core.multiply(splitImg.get(i), new Scalar(1.0 / count), temp);
            Core.add(average.get(i), temp, average.get(i));
        }
```

To verify that this is correct, here's the math I wrote out for this in LaTeX.  Given a signal of `N` values which we call `x`, we can calculate the mean with the first line of the equation.  `x_i` denotes the i<sup>th</sup> value of the signal `x`.  The second line and onwards is what would happen if we added an additional term to the mean.  If you work out the math, we verify that your equation in your code is correct... but you simply need to correct the `Core.divide` statement:

[image]

The left most term in the second equation is what you have in your first line of code in the loop which is correct:

```
Core.multiply(average.get(i), new Scalar((count - 1) / ((double) count)), average.get(i));
```

Finally to compute the second term of this equation, we do:

```
Core.multiply(splitImg.get(i), new Scalar(1.0 / count), temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

For numerical stability it's probably best to just store the accumulated sum image and divide that by the current N when you need the avg.

Just take care that you don't overflow.